# auto increment no in textbox From Database c#

Tags: c#

```
string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Max(VchNo) from tran1 where VchType=9 ", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);


            txtCIN.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            txtCIN.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(txtCIN.Text) + 1);
```

Comment: Hi Atul - please include some text that explains (a) what your question is (b) what your code is supposed to do and (c) what your code is actually doing and how that differs from what it is supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Max(VchNo) from tran1 where VchType=9 ", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
       string vchno = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
       string a = vchno;
       a = vchno.Substring(0,(a.Length-8));
       a = (int.Parse(a) + 1).ToString();
       txtCIN.Text = a +"/2018-19";
```